# No real eigenvalues in matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What does it geometrically mean for a matrix to not have an real eigenvalues? I know for rotations you do not get real eigenvalues but I think there are other cases too.

Comment: Rotations do _sometimes_ have real eigenvalues (of $\pm 1$ when $\theta = n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Oh, this is true. So it only works for certain matrices.

Comment: This means that there's not an invariant vector line.

Comment: What is an invariant vector line? And how does it affect if geometrically?

Comment: Do you know what the geometrical meaning is for a matrix that has least one eigenvalue?  If so, negate that meaning.

Comment: I do not. Could we start there then?

Comment: Would it mean that the vector in that plane is rotated onto another place on the plane. So if there is no eigenvalue it goes onto a different plane?

Comment: Possessing an eigenvalue in not in every case connected to rotations; consider projections for example.